# "Check with" or "check in with"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

> "check" in the meaning: to look at something or ask somebody to find out if something/somebody is present, correct or true or if something is how you think it is
> [(source: Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/check_1?q=check)

***Check with** your doctor before beginning any exercise programe.

You'd better **check with** Jane what time she's expecting us tonight.*

> "check in" [US] to find out or report the status of someone or something especially as part of a regular pattern of communication or monitoring (often followed by **on** or **with**)
> [(source: Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check%20in)

*I'm just **checking in with** you to find out how your doctor's appointment went.*

https://youtu.be/RECIiC5phwU?t=221 (3:41)
https://youtu.be/1qq7lDL-bzY?t=397 (6:37)

What is the difference between the two verbs in these situations? Are there any nuances? In what cases "*check in with*" used and in what ones "*check with*"?

Answer (score 1):

"Check with" is verifying or consultating something/someone, before doing/saying something.

"Check in with" is more of a nicety; letting someone know that you are (aware that they are) still there. Or, in your example, following up on something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).